# Percentagem de igualdade de Textos?

Tags: java, algoritmo

Existe algum método que permite saber a percentagem de igualdade de dois textos(Strings) em Java?

Um algorítimo abstrato também serviria.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Distância de Levenshtein é um dos algoritmos mais conhecidos para isso:

### Java:

```
public class Levenshtein {

    public static int distance(String a, String b) {
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
        // i == 0
        int [] costs = new int [b.length() + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < costs.length; j++)
            costs[j] = j;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++) {
            // j == 0; nw = lev(i - 1, j)
            costs[0] = i;
            int nw = i - 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= b.length(); j++) {
                int cj = Math.min(1 + Math.min(costs[j], costs[j - 1]), a.charAt(i - 1) == b.charAt(j - 1) ? nw : nw + 1);
                nw = costs[j];
                costs[j] = cj;
            }
        }
        return costs[b.length()];
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String [] data = { "kitten", "sitting", "saturday", "sunday", "rosettacode", "raisethysword" };
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 2)
            System.out.println("distance(" + data[i] + ", " + data[i+1] + ") = " + distance(data[i], data[i+1]));
    }
}
```

**Saída:**

```
distance(kitten, sitting) = 3
distance(saturday, sunday) = 3
distance(rosettacode, raisethysword) = 8
```

Se quiser a diferença em porcentagem, divida pelo tamanho da string e multiplique por 100.

**Fonte:**

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Java

### Demonstração em JavaScript:

```js
function levenshtein(str1, str2) {
  var m = str1.length,
      n = str2.length,
      d = [],
      i, j;

  if (!m) return n;
  if (!n) return m;

  for (i = 0; i <= m; i++) d[i] = [i];
  for (j = 0; j <= n; j++) d[0][j] = j;

  for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
      if (str1[i-1] == str2[j-1]) d[i][j] = d[i - 1][j - 1];
      else d[i][j] = Math.min(d[i-1][j], d[i][j-1], d[i-1][j-1]) + 1;
    }
  }
  return d[m][n];
}


function calc() {
  var t1 = document.getElementById('t1');
  var t2 = document.getElementById('t2');
  var r1 = document.getElementById('r1');
  var d  = levenshtein( t1.value, t2.value );
  r1.innerHTML = d;
  r2.innerHTML = ( 100 - Math.floor( 100 * d / Math.max( t1.value.length, t2.value.length))) + '%';
}
```

```html
Palavra 1:<br>
<input id="t1" type="text" onKeyUp="calc()"><br>
Palavra 2:<br>
<input id="t2" type="text" onKeyUp="calc()"><br>
Distancia:<br>
<div id="r1">?</div>
Similaridade:<br>
<div id="r2">?</div>
```

Comment: agradeço. Só para enriquecer, achei isto http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures.

Comment: @Cold é uma boa referência. Elabore uma resposta nesse sentido, acho que seria uma alternativa interessante.

Comment: Não poderei faze-lo agora @Bacco (seria ótimo enriqueceres já a tua respostas com outras referências, no meu ponto de vista :D). Só pra deixar no ponto, coloque ele mostrando já a percentagem :).

Comment: @Cold pus o cálculo de % na versão JS, como referência :)

Comment: Ainda estava aqui me matando na lógica da obtenção da percetangem, como/porquê fizeste assim?

Comment: Primeiro, dividi a distância obtida com a fórmula pelo tamanho da maior string (max), pois ela é baseada em caracteres. Depois, multipliquei por 100 pra obter a porcentagem de diferença. Como queriamos a similaridade, tirei a diferença obtida de 100% (por isso o 100 - (...). O Math.floor foi só pra saída não ficar "feia", com quebrados do tipo 33.3333333 etc.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18008/discussion-between-cold-and-bacco).